# Finding the derivative of $y=12x^4\sqrt[3]{x^2}-2e^x+9$

Tags: derivatives

Let 
$$
y=12x^4\sqrt[3]{x^2}-2e^x+9
$$
How can we find $y^\prime$?

Comment: Are you asked to find the derivative?

Comment: Yes, prime derivative of 'y'.

Comment: Using the table derivatives.

Comment: To begin with try combining the powers $x^4(x^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Comment: You will almost surely need to use more than one of the formulas from your table of derivatives.

Answer (score 3):

$$\require{cancel} y=12x^4\underbrace{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}_{x^\frac23}-2e^x+9=12x^\frac{14}3-2e^x+9\\\frac{dy}{dx}=\cancelto{4}{12}\left(\frac{14}{\cancel{3}}\right)(x^\frac{11}3)-2e^x+0\\=56x^\frac{11}3-2e^x$$